# Finding integer to satisfy modular equation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find an integer x that satisfies a modular equation, and can't get my head wrapped around it...

Given two integers $n$ and $m$ in the range $[0, 2^{32})$, I need to calculate an integer $x$ such that

$x n\equiv m\pmod{2^{32}}$

Any suggestions for doing this without checking all $2^{32}$ possible values of $x$ for a match?

Edit: $n$ is known to be a specific large prime. For the case I'm currently trying to solve, $n=1167002411$.

Comment: Sometimes it isn't possible: for example for $m=1$ and $n=2$ ($nx$ is always even).

Comment: @agha Good point. However, I know that n is a "large" prime number, which means there will always be exactly one value of x in [0, 2^32) to satisfy the equation.

Comment: Is $m$ necessarily smaller than $n$?

Comment: @barakmanos no, m can be any value in [0 to 2^32).

Comment: You're essentially looking for a "wrap-around", i.e., a value of $x$ which, when multiplied by $n$, will yield a result larger than 32-bit, with the least 32-bit value of that result being equal to $m$.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, that describes it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the congruence relation,

$$1167002411x \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{32}}$$

We can rewrite this as an absolute equation (for some integer $y$):
$$1167002411x + 2^{32}y = 1$$

Since $1167002411$ and $2^{32}$ are coprime, it follows from [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) that there exists integers $(x,y)$ which satisfy the above equation.

By using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we can easily (that is, with a computer) come up with the following solution:

$$(x, y) = (3456064387, -939060811)$$

However we are only interested in $x$, so we will take $x = 3456064387$ as the solution. In other words,

$$3456064387\cdot1167002411 \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{32}}$$

You can verify this yourself using [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3456064387%2a1167002411%20mod%202%5E32). Up till this point, what we have done is to essentially compute the inverse of $n$ modulo $2^{32}$.

Now, simply multiply both sides by $m$. We see that

$$(3456064387m)\cdot n \equiv m \pmod {2^{32}}$$

In other words, $x = 3456064387m$ will always be a solution. If this product overflows on your computer, simply take it modulo $2^{32}$.

---

More generally, given the congruence relation:

$$ax = b \pmod n$$

the solutions for $x$ is given by

$$x \equiv a^{-1}b \pmod n$$

where $a^{-1}$ is the modulo inverse of $a$ mod $n$ (assuming it exists).